# HTTPS and external (CDN) hosted files?

Tags: jquery, yui, cdn

I have a page that references a couple of externally hosted javascript files - namely, [jQuery on Google](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) and [YUI using YUI Loader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuiloader/).

The trouble is when I access the page via HTTPS the browser complains of mixed insecure content, since the external javascript files are being accessed using http instead of https.

What's a good way to deal with this, accessing the external jQuery and YUI Loader objects with HTTPS?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Assuming the CDN provider has an https version, you can use protocol-relative URLs.

For example, instead of:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js
```

...you can use:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js
```

The browser will use the page's protocol to try to obtain the file. On non-secure pages, http. On secure pages, https.

Google also makes YUI Loader available through its CDN. So for YUI this works fine:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.8.0/build/yuiloader/yuiloader-min.js
```

...in both http and https contexts.

Comment: Nice, didn't realize you can leave off the protocol. Will give this a try.

Answer (score 7):

Google hosts them under https

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.8.1/build/yuiloader/yuiloader-min.js

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js