# Advantages of CDN content served via https over http

Tags: google-cdn

All of google's CDN [libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#Libraries) are served via http**s**. Is there any advantage of serving them via https over http ?

Comment: They're served over both; you can use HTTP instead of HTTPS if you prefer, but I think cdhowie is correct (that's why *I* use their HTTPS versions anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I had to venture a guess, they recommend those URLs so that if your page is served via HTTPS, browsers will not whine about your page containing "insecure content."

Answer (score 13):

cdhowie is correct. If your page is served via http, then serving the library via https merely adds a small amount of overhead. If your page is served via https, then serving the library via http would be a potential security hazard, and most browsers will issue a warning. So https is given as the default option.

See this related question: [HTTPS and external (CDN) hosted files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622598/https-and-external-cdn-hosted-files)

But you can have the best of both worlds by omitting the protocol entirely, e.g.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That tells the browser to automatically use the same protocol that was used to serve the page. Little-known trick, but widely supported. More info here: [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Comment: Why I never know the *//* double slash is a valid URL in src script. Is that compatible for all browsers in all platform and w3c standard?

Comment: Yep, it even works in IE6. Look at the "Is it valid" link at the end of my question. It's a little-known trick that deserves to be much more widely used.

Comment: I comes from RFC 3986 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.2 It uses the document's underlying protocol, therefore it does work for HTTP/HTTPS, but doesn't for file://

Comment: +1 for mentioning the **security hazard**. It's the true reason. Man in the middle. "security hazard" should be in the bold font and without _potential_ word ahead.