# HTTPS and HTTP Mixed Content in IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: apache, internet-explorer-8, https, mixed-mode

I have an application that I would like to be mostly ssl based but allow http links to coexist on https pages in IE7 and IE8. When I put mixed content (embed http links on https served pages) I get mixed content warnings from IE.  Is there any way around this?  We are using a security certificate, do certain certs handle mixed content?  Firefox and Chrome don't throw any errors...any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way round this - it is a browser restriction, and it is up to the user to allow the mixed content or not. If you are serving over SSL then the whole page should be served that way, which means you should also serve your stylesheets, scripts and images securely (even if they are sourced from a CDN).

For a good answer on how to use links that are protocol agnostic (i.e. they work whether the protocol is http or https), check [this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622598/https-and-external-cdn-hosted-files/3622615#3622615). Another good resource I've recently become aware of is this blog post: [The protocol-relative URL](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)