# Node.js post request local file

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm writing an server script with node.js which includes an request.
I'm wondering if you could send an post request to local file like:

```
var request = require('request');
request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/v1/functions.php',
    formData: {
        'method': 'validate',
        'id': message.id,
        'token': message.token
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    console.log('response: '+ response.statusCode);
    console.log('body: '+ body);
});
```

But this is throwing an error:

```
Error: Invalid URI "/v1/functions.php"
```

It works if I use the full path:

```
http://localhost/something/something/v1/functions.php
```

Comment: no you cannot send it like this you have to provide complete path including http://

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. Request states in their [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback) the url/uri must be fully qualified

> uri || url - fully qualified uri or a parsed url object from url.parse()

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17407082/1309377) describing a fully qualified URI

An alternative to read a local file is reading it using [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback). Here is an example

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/functions.php', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```