# How to generate full URL with ASP.NET Core outside the views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an application that is written on the top of ASP.NET Core 2.2 framework. I need to create JSON-Ld data which requires a full URL. The object that I want to convert to JSON-Ld is generated using a service class. Within my service class, I want to be able to create the full URL.

I tried to create the URLs using the [`LinkGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class after injecting it into the construction of my service class. However, the `LinkGenerator` generates relevant URI, not the fully qualified URL (excluding the domain).

I also tried to create an instance of [`UrlHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper?view=aspnetcore-2.2) hoping I can use it to generate fully qualified URLs. After injecting [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.2) into the service contractor, I tried to create an instance of `UrlHelper` like so

```
var httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext);
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(httpContextBase);
```

However, `new UrlHelper(httpContextBase)` throws the following exception

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

How can I correctly generate fully qualified URLs from a service class?

Comment: A "fully qualified URL", by definition, includes the domain. It is usually referred to as an "absolute URL" in web standard documents though: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17406848/215552

Answer (score 4):

I found one way to do it using `LinkGenerator`

I injected `IHttpContextAccessor` and `LinkGenerator` in the constructor of my service class. Then I generated the full URI like so

```
var url = LinkGenerator.GetUriByAction("index", "home", null, HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme, HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host);
```

Comment: So how do we add area to the options, mine does not show the Identity Area after generating the Link, here by showing error 404 @junior

Comment: new { area = "Identity" } as one of the args