# Correct way of saving objects with URLField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model class `KeyWord`

```
class KeyWord(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(verbose_name="Topic",max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField(verbose_name = "Next Best Action", max_length=500,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword
```

If i create an object like this:

```
KeyWord.objects.create(keyword="hello",link="world")
```

Ideally an error be raised because i am assigning normal text to `link` field which is a `URLField` but object created successfully?

**Which field should i use or what should i do so that objects with valid links are saved?**

Comment: Why is it not a valid URL? This resolves to the url "world" relative to the current document location. So if document location is http://hello.com/ then the URL world would be http://hello.com/world. There is no way to force the vanilla Django URLField to require fully qualified URLs.

Comment: Actually i am saving objects by reading data from excel file. I want to raise an error if i don't get a  valid link. e.g if at any certain row if get ```keyword="macbook"``` and ```link="https://apple.com"``` i will save that object else if get ```keyword="macbook"``` and ```link="apple"``` then an error meesage will be passed that ```apple is not a valid url``` and function will return.

Comment: I hope i made my question clear now and you can guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-requisite: model validation only happens when you call `full_clean()`. If you use a ModelForm, this is done for you when you call `form.save()`, but if you upload an Excel file with custom view logic, then you need to [do this yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects):

> There are three steps involved in validating a model:
>
> - Validate the model fields - Model.clean_fields()
> - Validate the model as a whole - Model.clean()
> - Validate the field uniqueness - Model.validate_unique()
>
> All three steps are performed when you call a model’s full_clean() method.

As I said earlier, there's no way to tell the URLField to require [fully qualified URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17407082). For that you need to override the URLValidator.

That has a very nasty regular expression and you probably do not want to mess with that, so an alternative is to add additional validators:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class RequireHttpOrHttpsUrl:
    def __call__(self, value):
        if not value.startswith("http://") and not value.startswith("https://"):
            raise ValidationError('Please provide a http or https resource')

class KeyWord(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(verbose_name="Topic",max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField(
        verbose_name = "Next Best Action",
        max_length=500, null=True,
        validators=[RequireHttpOrHttpsUrl()]
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword
```

On using urllib.parse() as suggested in the comments:

I highly suggest playing around with URLValidator to where urllib.parse() does better. URLValidator rejects:

- http://
- http://bla
- https://bla

Accepts:

- http://a.com
- http://bla.com/
- https://localhost

So, I can't find the upside to adding another parser.

Comment: You can use urllib to make it a bit more rigorous too (example with Python 3.8)

```python
from urllib.parse import urlparse

parsed = urlparse('https://apple.com/foo')

bool(parsed.scheme) and bool(parsed.netloc) # True
```

Comment: That's not needed, because the default URLValidator is still there, which does a good enough job.

Comment: First i applied migrations ```python manage.py makemigrations appName``` and then ```python manage.py migrate```. Then i again uploaded the excel file. Still values with ```non http and https``` got saved. However i followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not and found the fix. Thanks for your support though.

Comment: @Melvyn it's not about verifying that it's a valid URL, it's about letting the parser do the heavy-lifting of determining which components of the URL are present. In my example case, verifying that we have both the schema and the domain.

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney You probably used the earlier version, I added the validator as a class not an instance before the edit.

Comment: @Melvyn Sir now i am getting this error ```ValueError: Cannot serialize: <sentimentwebapp.models.RequireHttpOrHttpsUrl object at 0x04212410>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing```

Comment: @AndrewIngram Yeah, true I guess. It's all not too computation heavy anyway. I find it a bit overkill for the fact that you can still create urls with hostnames that aren't valid, but give an illusion that you have "real" urls.

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney Ack, sorry, did this from top of my head and I know I shouldn't. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @Melvyn I wish i could show you but again it saved ```non http and https```. Please edit the spelling ```deconstrucible``` to ```deconstructible``` in the answer. This time no error encountered during migrations.

Comment: Then you are not validating your model. You must call `instance.full_clean()` for validators to work. If you just call `save()`, then your validation is bypassed. See [the documation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

Comment: @Melvyn I called ```instance.full_clean()``` method before saving object and it worked. Thanks !