# Google jQuery from CDN with SSL - Issues with iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, https, cdn

Since updating my iPad the other day and testing a new website on it, I soon realised that jQuery was not working throughout my application, but is working fine everywhere else (desktop browsers etc).

After a couple of hours trying to debug my code, I simply built a blank page and included the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        alert("jQuery loaded");
    } else {
        alert("jQuery NOT loaded");
    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        alert("DOM ready.");
    });
</script>
```

On my desktop machine I get two alerts; "jQuery loaded" and "DOM ready".
On my iPad I get only one alert; "jQuery NOT loaded".

I then found the changing `HTTPS://ajax.googleapis.com...` to `HTTP://ajax.googleapis.com...` makes it load without any problems.

What am I missing here? Has anything changed recently that would cause this? I'd like to use HTTPS throughout my application, so I need to fix this/learn from it really. Any help of experience gratefully received.

Comment: Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622598/https-and-external-cdn-hosted-files

Comment: @MartinKonecny, already seen that question and not really related either.

Comment: Can you load the file if you paste it into your address bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```