# export "saved for later" from (evil) feedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, https, feedly

i'm trying to migrate from feedly as it is unacceptable (at least to me) that a search query is (fully) enabled only by a pro version.

Anyhow, to export my lengthy list of "saved for later" i found some lovely scripts:
[Simple script that exports a users "Saved For Later" list out of Feedly as a JSON string](https://gist.github.com/bradcrawford/7288411)  and [feedly-to-pocket](https://github.com/ShockwaveNN/feedly-to-pocket). where i am instructed to:

> You must switch off SSL (http rather than https) or jQuery won't load!

so i though i did by adding (ubuntu 14.04/chrome 40 x64)

```
--ssl-version-min=tls1
```

to my /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop file (all lines starting with Exec=). However when i try to run it in the browser console i get

> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

So, any suggestions? (*also, excuse me for noobness*)

Comment: also, ifft does not count as an alternative (requires to enable pro feedly for any IF/DO)

Comment: wow tough crowd downvoting for grammar mistakes (fixed:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted the question in the jquery forum and the solution was rather simple (remove http from attribute string)

> line 34 should be
>     script.setAttribute('src', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');

So to close the loop - for a full searchable/archived list of links not only by title/url but **context** also(!) you can:

1. Follow the instructions in https://github.com/ShockwaveNN/feedly-to-pocket (with the correction suggested by kind stranger jakecigar and you also have to register a pocket app (obtain consumer key) for the ruby script to work)
2. Export html list from your pocket account
3. Import pocket list to a [Kifi](https://www.kifi.com) library

and at last feedly-free with my personal search engine

Comment: somewhat related: [https-and-external-cdn-hosted-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622598/https-and-external-cdn-hosted-files)

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to your [Feedly "saved" list](https://feedly.com/i/saved) and scroll down until all articles have loaded.
2. Open console and paste the following Javascript into it:

   ```
   function loadJQuery() {

       script = document.createElement('script');
       script.setAttribute('src', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js');
       script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
       script.onload = loadSaveAs;
       document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
   }

   function loadSaveAs() {

       saveAsScript = document.createElement('script');
       saveAsScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/5733e40e5af936eb3f48554cf6a8a7075d71d18a/FileSaver.js');
       saveAsScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
       saveAsScript.onload = saveToFile;
       document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(saveAsScript);
   }

   function saveToFile() {

       // Loop through the DOM, grabbing the information from each bookmark
       map = jQuery(".entry.quicklisted").map(function(i, el) {
           var $el = jQuery(el);
           var regex = /Published:(.*)(.*)/i;
           return {
               title: $el.attr("data-title"),
               url: $el.attr("data-alternate-link"),
               summary: $el.find(".summary")[0].innerHTML,
               time: regex.exec($el.find("span.ago").attr("title"))[1]
           };
       }).get(); // Convert jQuery object into an array

       // Convert to a nicely indented JSON string
       json = JSON.stringify(map, undefined, 2);
       var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
       saveAs(blob, "FeedlySavedForLater" + Date.now().toString() + ".txt");
   }

   loadJQuery()
   ```

Source: [Feedly-Export-Save4Later](https://github.com/dotEsuS/Feedly-Export-Save4Later/blob/master/script)

Answer (score 3):

Not javascript but here is how I saved a html page with all the links and excerpts...

1. Open the saved pages in feedly in chrome
2. scroll down so they are all there
3. inspect any element (the top article is a good choice) so it opens the generated html
4. find the `div id="section0_column0"` node
5. right-click & copy it
6. paste into Notepad++
7. this html is untidy so carry on...
8. Do a Regex find & replace

   1. find: `(?s)<div id=.+?_main.+?>.+?(<a href=")(.+?)(").+?sans-serif">(.+?)</span>.+?</div>.+?</div>.+?</div>`
   2. replace: `<div>$1$2$3>$2</a></div> <div> $4<br />&nbsp;<br /></div>`
9. save the html page.
10. open it in Chrome

Comment: btw, what does (?s) do? I don't use notepad++, I don't know its syntax

Comment: @ijverig `(?s)` is Regex single line mode. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html . I haven't looked at Feedly since I went to Innoreader, if Feedly has changed since then this may not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party but Ive been hunting around for a few days to find a reasonably simple solution. None of which have been listed clearly or concisely on stack overflow or elsewhere on the web. I have in fact found a much easier way to do this.

1. Use this java script from this Gist just as it instructs https://gist.github.com/ShockwaveNN/a0baf2ca26d1711f10e2 (Note this is referenced above and found through the link @gep shared in step one)

   - Once the JS as completed running it will download a text file. (It does still run successfully and on large numbers, I just exported almost 2500 articles)
2. Create a blank test.json in SublimeText.
3. Copy all entries from your exported text file into this json file

   - Weirdly it does seem you need to copy and past as I tried just               renaming the text file and when I did that I received errors on the next step
4. Make sure you are signed into pocket
5. Go here: https://getpocket.com/import/springpad
6. Select your newly created test.json
7. Upload

   - Note: On large uploads the import page fails to refresh (this did not seem to be an issue as all my articles did make it into my account)

This allows you to directly upload json into your pocket account. Thus no more messing around with random supposed other fixes. I hope this make it a lot easier for everyone in the future.

Comment: "https://getpocket.com/import/springpad" says page not found. Is there a new URL?

Comment: not that im aware of, but this is 6 years old at this point and I quit using feedly after i exported all of this